# Alterar estrutura de Array no PHP

Tags: php

Recebo um Array que está com a estrutura abaixo, e gostaria de despoluir a mesma alterando os valores das chaves ex: `[19741N]`, que são valores aleatórios por valores numéricos crescentes `0 => 99999999999999`:

```
Array
(
    [19741N] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 19741N
            [TipoDoImovel] => RESIDENCIAL
            [TipoImovel] => 
            [Finalidade] => VENDA
            [Venda] => Nao
            [Dormitorio] => 3
            [Dormitorios] => 4
            [TotalBanheiros] => 3
            [Estacionamento] => Nao
            [EstacionamentoVagas] => 
            [AreaConstruida] => 316.37
            [AreaTotal] => 
            [Endereco] => CARLOS PARUCKER
            [Numero] => 281
            [Complemento] => 
            [Bairro] => Atiradores
            [Cidade] => Joinville
            [UF] => SC
            [CEP] => 89203170
            [ValorVenda] => 980000
            [ValorAluguel] => 
            [ValorIptu] => 
            [ValorCondominio] => 
        )

[1238NA] => Array
        (
            [Codigo] => 13719
            [TipoDoImovel] => RESIDENCIAL
            [TipoImovel] => 
            [Finalidade] => VENDA
            [Venda] => Nao
            [Dormitorio] => 2
            [Dormitorios] => 3
            [TotalBanheiros] => 4
            [Estacionamento] => Nao
            [EstacionamentoVagas] => 
            [AreaConstruida] => 118.62
            [AreaTotal] => 
            [Endereco] => ITAIOPOLIS
            [Numero] => 651
            [Complemento] => 33
            [Bairro] => Saguaçu
            [Cidade] => Joinville
            [UF] => SC
            [CEP] => 89221155
            [ValorVenda] => 280000
            [ValorAluguel] => 
            [ValorIptu] => 
            [ValorCondominio] => 280
        )
)
```

Quero elimitar o primeiro nível, no caso o `[19741N]`, e esse valor é aleatório, tentei fazer uso do [array_column()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-column.php), mas não deu certo retorna apenas `array {  }` , para um valor apenas funciona, mas não para a estrutura toda acima, para ficar igual a debaixo:

```
Array
(
    [0] => array {
        [Codigo] => 19741N
        [TipoDoImovel] => RESIDENCIAL
        [TipoImovel] => 
        [Finalidade] => VENDA
        [Venda] => Nao
        [Dormitorio] => 3
        [Dormitorios] => 4
        [TotalBanheiros] => 3
        [Estacionamento] => Nao
        [EstacionamentoVagas] => 
        [AreaConstruida] => 316.37
        [AreaTotal] => 
        [Endereco] => CARLOS PARUCKER
        [Numero] => 281
        [Complemento] => 
        [Bairro] => Atiradores
        [Cidade] => Joinville
        [UF] => SC
        [CEP] => 89203170
        [ValorVenda] => 980000
        [ValorAluguel] => 
        [ValorIptu] => 
        [ValorCondominio] => 
    },
    [1] => array {
        [Codigo] => 13719
        [TipoDoImovel] => RESIDENCIAL
        [TipoImovel] => 
        [Finalidade] => VENDA
        [Venda] => Nao
        [Dormitorio] => 2
        [Dormitorios] => 3
        [TotalBanheiros] => 4
        [Estacionamento] => Nao
        [EstacionamentoVagas] => 
        [AreaConstruida] => 118.62
        [AreaTotal] => 
        [Endereco] => ITAIOPOLIS
        [Numero] => 651
        [Complemento] => 33
        [Bairro] => Saguaçu
        [Cidade] => Joinville
        [UF] => SC
        [CEP] => 89221155
        [ValorVenda] => 280000
        [ValorAluguel] => 
        [ValorIptu] => 
        [Descricao] => Amplo apartamento muito bem localizado, próximo ao Sesc , 3 dormitórios sendo 1 suíte , cozinha com móveis planejados- sacada-  2 vagas de garagem.
        [ValorCondominio] => 280
    }
```

Comment: Veja a função `array_values`

Comment: de primeira, gravei $arr2 = array_values($arr); e feito. obrigado

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss faça uma resposta para ele :)

Comment: @CypherPotato Sem tempo, pode fazer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o `array_values` para criar um `array` onde tenha apenas os valores, e portanto, as chaves serão índices e não `keys`:

```
$array = [
    "aaa" => 12581,
    "bbb" => 182,
    "ccc" => "valor"
];

echo var_dump(array_values($array));
```

Saída:

```
array(3) {
    [0]=> int(12581)
    [1]=> int(182)
    [2]=> string(5) "valor" 
}
```

---

Documentação do [`array_values`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-values.php).

Comment: Obrigado! Havia dado certo e foi assim mesmo que precisava.